# Some properties of the largest abelian $p$-factor group and its kernel $A^p(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $A^p(G)$ be the unique smallest normal subgroup of $G$ for which the corresponding factor group is an abelian $p$-group (that $A^p(G)$ is well-defined is an immediate consequence of the fact that if $M, N \unlhd G$ and both $G / M$ and $G / N$ are ablian $p$-groups, then $G / (M\cap N)$ is an abelian $p$-group). Also denote by $O^p(G)$ be the smallest normal subgroup such that $G / O^p(G)$ is a $p$-group.

Then:

1) $|A^p(G) : G'|$ is not divisible by $p$,

2) $G / A^p(G)$ is isomorphic to the largest abelian factor of $G / O^p(G)$, thus $A^p(G) / O^p(G) = (G / O^p(G))'$.

Why does 1) and 2) hold? I see that as $O^p(G) \le A^p(G)$ we have 
$$
 G / A^p(G) \cong (G / O^p(G)) / (A^p(G) / O^p(G)) 
$$
which implies, as $G / A^p(G)$ is abelian, that $(G / O^p(G))' \le A^p(G) / O^p(G)$; but not the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A^p(G)/G'$ is an abelian group, so if it had order divisible by $p$ then it would have a  subgroup (a $p$-complement) $N/G'$ with $(A^p(G)/G')/(N/G') \cong A^p(G)/N$ a nontrivial $p$-group. Now $G/N$ is an abelian $p$-group of order larger than $G/A^p(G)$, contradiction.

The proof of 2) is similar. If it was false then there would be a larger abelian $p$-factor group than $G/A^p(G)$.